How to have Mixed Linestyles and Colors in Matplotlib
I would like to create a line chart with two different line styles in a single chart while customizing the color in each line on a pandas dataframe. For example, if the below customer spends over 100, they are flagged as a "Premium" customer. Otherwise, they are a "Standard" customer.
My goal is to plot how much the customer is spending a week, using a solid line when Premium. I am stuck on how to color code the customer's line and using multiple line styles. Is this possible?
'''
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date': ['9/1/2024', '9/8/2024', '9/15/2024', '9/22/2024', '9/27/2024', '10/3/2024', '9/1/2024', '9/8/2024', '9/15/2024', '9/22/2024', '9/27/2024', '10/3/2024', '9/1/2024', '9/8/2024', '9/15/2024', '9/22/2024', '9/27/2024', '10/3/2024'],
        'Customer': ['Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C'],
        'Spend': [100, 200, 10, 150, 180, 200, 100, 200, 10, 15, 200, 200, 100, 200, 10, 10, 300, 150],
        'Color': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow']}
df['PurchaseType'] = np.where(df['Spend']>=100, 'A', 'B')

'''
I've tried masking the data similar to this post Replacing part of a plot with a dotted line but am stuck at the plotting.

To help you further, consider uploading the current plot and the plot that you would want (desired results)

You could do something like this.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['9/1/2024', '9/8/2024', '9/15/2024', '9/22/2024', '9/27/2024', '10/3/2024', '9/1/2024', '9/8/2024', '9/15/2024', '9/22/2024', '9/27/2024', '10/3/2024', '9/1/2024', '9/8/2024', '9/15/2024', '9/22/2024', '9/27/2024', '10/3/2024'],
        'Customer': ['Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C', 'Customer C'],
        'Spend': [100, 200, 10, 150, 180, 200, 100, 200, 10, 15, 200, 200, 100, 200, 10, 10, 300, 150],
        'Color': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['PurchaseType'] = np.where(df['Spend']>=100, 'A', 'B')

colors = list(df['Color'].unique())
ax1 = sns.lineplot(data = df, x= 'Date', y = 'Spend', hue='Customer',style='PurchaseType' ,palette=colors)

ax1.get_legend().remove()


To add horizontal line separating A and B categories:
colors = list(df['Color'].unique())
ax1 = sns.lineplot(data = df, x= 'Date', y = 'Spend', hue='Customer' ,palette=colors, zorder=0)

ax1.axhline(100, ls='--', c='green')


Not quite! I was looking for a way for the dotted red and solid red to be connected and dotted orange with solid orange, which was the part I was also stuck on.

It might be easier to add a horizontal line in that case. Will that work for you?

It unfortunately would not work as I'm trying to automatically display when the customer is spending more and less if that makes sense, similar in the link I provided but by another column.

(1)Can you make an attempt from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549047/how-to-apply-a-linestyle-to-a-specific-line-in-seaborn-lineplot ? It allows you to reference each line individually.
(2)You can also find the slope of the lines( 9-08-2024 to 9-15-2024 and 9-15 to 9-22), find x coordinates for when y=100 for all the customers and label that as 'B'. Once you have that you can plot all the data with zorder=1 and then a second plot of the data, on the same graph, with category 'B' (zorder=2).
(3)Another option is stacked bar chart.
